# Windows Desktop not recognising phone

Tags: 8.0, windows-live, windows-7

I'm sure this is an utterly futile attempt, but I'll ask it anyway!

My phone (like so many others) made friends with a concrete floor yesterday.  There's only 1 crack across the screen, but I have no graphics.  My insurance company are going to sort out a repair (or replacement).  When I plug the phone into my Windows 7 laptop, Windows Desktop and Dropbox both recognise that a Windows Phone has been attached, but say there's no data to transfer.  The Windows Desktop App also recognises that my phone is attached, but says I need to unlock it - this is pretty hard to do with no graphics!

- Is it likely my touchscreen functionality has failed too (and hence 'guessing' where to swipe so I can unlock my phone won't work)?
- is there anyway of getting all data / settings off the phone? Luckily, my photos and contacts are saved to Gmail / Live, so I have those (which are probably the most important things) - but texts / app data etc aren't.  I also have an app on there which isn't published anymore which would be nice to keep

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine if someone steals your phone. They'd have access to everything even if they did know your code! That's not good and therefor you're unable to access the data on a locked phone.

On your next phone, enable backup to OneDrive before you do anything else!

Comment: As it happened, my phone had backed up virtually everything; it hadn't backed up my app list / app settings because I was running an old build of WP8

Comment: Ok. I just did a reset of my phone and choose to restore nothing. I do not regret it.